# How do I get pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN to only go once per click?

Tags: python, math, pygame, click, mouse

I'm stumped. My main goal currently is to be able to have the user click on a circle and the number at the top left of the screen to go up by one each time it is pressed (Trying to make a basic clicker game). I've gotten it to a point where when you click on the circle the number does go up! Except the number goes up more than once. Here's the function the code is in:

```
def bubble():
orange = (255, 165, 0)
dark_orange = (255, 140, 0)
bubble_color = dark_orange
bubble_x = 300
bubble_y = 400
bubble_pos = (bubble_x, bubble_y)
bubble_rad = 100
mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
distance = math.hypot(bubble_x - mouse_x, bubble_y - mouse_y)
if bubble_rad >= distance:
    bubble_color = orange
if bubble_rad >= distance and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    global kill_counter
    kill_counter += 1
pygame.draw.circle(screen, bubble_color, bubble_pos, bubble_rad)
```

I've tried changing the mousebuttondown to mousebutton up but the same problem was happening just only after I clicked (it would stop when I moved the mouse). Next I tried to  do this:

```
if bubble_rad >= distance and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP
```

It didn't work which makes sense because the mouse cant be up and down at the same time. Is there a way to make it so the kill_counter only goes up when the mouse is clicked and then un-clicked? Here's my whole code just in case the problem lies out there.

```
import math

pygame.init()

# General
display_width = 600
display_height = 800
background = pygame.image.load("background.png")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("SLASHR")
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("knifeart.png"))

# Global variables
kill_counter = 0


# Functions
def counter():
    font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 52)
    crimson = (220, 20, 60)
    screen.blit(font.render("Kill Count: " + str(kill_counter), True, crimson), (0, 10))


def bubble():
    orange = (255, 165, 0)
    dark_orange = (255, 140, 0)
    bubble_color = dark_orange
    bubble_x = 300
    bubble_y = 400
    bubble_pos = (bubble_x, bubble_y)
    bubble_rad = 100
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    distance = math.hypot(bubble_x - mouse_x, bubble_y - mouse_y)
    if bubble_rad >= distance:
        bubble_color = orange
    if bubble_rad >= distance and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        global kill_counter
        kill_counter += 1
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, bubble_color, bubble_pos, bubble_rad)


# Game Loop
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    counter()
    bubble()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Thank you in advance for reading and helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

The `if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` should be in the `for event in pygame.event.get()` loop, im guessing that after the loop, event is still MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and doesnt get reset,

try:

```
# Game Loop
running = True
click = False #have click variable
while running:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        click = True
```

then in the bubble function:

```
def bubble():
    #other code
    if bubble_rad >= distance and click:
        global kill_counter
        kill_counter += 1
```